# Pandas regex replace value from another column

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have 2 pandas columns, one has filepath and another column has new folder name, i am trying to replace the folder name with new folder name using regex replace

```
df['new_path'] = df.root.str.replace(r'A-[0-9]*-END', df.new_folder_name)
```

I am getting an error  repl must be a string or callable , is it possible to replace matched regex with value from corresponding column?

Comment: I don't think `str.replace` allow it. You may extract values by the regex pattern and combine them with `df.new_folder_name` to construct a `dict` to use with `replace`

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the pattern first and then use `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"filename":[1,2,3],
                   "filepath":["C:/A-1-END","C:/A-12342-END","D:/A-777-END"],
                   "new_folder_name":["newfolder1","newfolder2","newfolder3"]})

pat = re.compile(r"A-[0-9]*-END", re.IGNORECASE)

df["new_path"] = df[["filepath","new_folder_name"]].apply(lambda x: pat.sub(repl=x[1],string=x[0]),axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   filename        filepath new_folder_name       new_path
0         1      C:/A-1-END      newfolder1  C:/newfolder1
1         2  C:/A-12342-END      newfolder2  C:/newfolder2
2         3    D:/A-777-END      newfolder3  D:/newfolder3
```

Comment: Hi @Henry, any idea why is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67810759/series-replace-not-working-with-regex-for-pandas-1-0-5/67811446#67811446 not working?